# windows connect for svn

Tags: windows, svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install subversion server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29247/how-to-install-subversion-server)

I am wondering if there is any possible approach for this. I am planning to build our SVN repository locally on my Ubuntu machine. Some of my team will be using windows and will be needing to connect on my Ubuntu for the SVN repository actions. Anyone can please provide me with some steps (if this is feasible). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The SVN server is independent of the client. The windows clients should work with the svn protocol ([additional libraries](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) might be necessary for SASL authentication), http is generally supported well.

The server can be Apache serving over WebDAV or a svnserve daemon. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion for more details.